# Rails routing with a parameter that includes slash(/)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to set the routings as follows

- `/url/http://google.com` to `urls` controller and `index` action.

What I have now in `routes.rb` is:

```
match "urls/:url" => "urls#index"
```

The routing doesn't seem to work because the slashed in `:url`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could do something similar to

```
match "urls/:url" => "urls#index", :constraints => {:url => /.*/}
```

in Rails 2.3 which may work in Rails 3 to allow you to match the / in the :url (although, I can't test this at the moment.)

Answer (score 40):

Or you can use Route Globbing:

```
match "urls/*url" => "urls#index"
```

You can access the values in your controller via 
`params[:url]`

Reference:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
Search for "Route Globbing"

Comment: Alright, but what if this is in a namespace? If I do this: `match '/services/:controller/*path/:id' => "/services/:controller#show", :via => :get` and go to `/services/foo/a/b` I get `uninitialized constant FooController`. `/services/foo` and `/services/foo/a` work, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
get ':klass/:id', constraints: { klass: /\D*/ }
```