# How can I get rails routes to match * for the final parameter of my url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I would like to allow a user to automatically login if they use their encrypted password in the url.  I have the following url that I would like matched with rails routes:

```
/attendants/update_player_status/game/1/maybe/user_hash/$2a$10$1kY8xvOjkqZJJJGWDd0q2Oeyl7kICSBDPTYzGhkJ6pZnE6YA/nJie
```

where the latter part of the url can have any characters, like * (ie. it can have '/' '$' '*' etc)

My routes works but then it bombs out on '/' in the parameter (as seen above):

```
match '/attendants/update_player_status/game/:game_id/:status/user_hash/:user_hash' => 'attendants#update_player_status_using_hash', :as => 'update_player_status_using_hash'
```

Any recommendations on what I should do?  Once i pull the parameter correctly I will use it to login the user into the website, and allow very limited access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is [route globbing](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing) (from the docs):

```
match 'photos/*other' => 'photos#unknown'

# In controller, params[:other] is everything after 'photos'
```

You could also use a regex in the match's `constraints` to allow a slash, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273205/rails-routing-with-a-parameter-that-includes-slash).

IMO the globbing is a bit more elegant; it may depend on the rest of your routes which is the best solution.