# Interpret part of request url as parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm currently working on something that would interpret part of the request url as a relative path (yes, I'm aware that this could pose a security risk).

It would look something like

```
/page/path/to/something
```

The parameter part would be `/path/to/something`.

Can I do this with regular routing or do I have to use something like rails metal to handle this myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [routing constraint](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-constraints) to allow slashes in route segments; nutshell (roughly):

```
match "page/:fqp" => "what#ever", :constraints => { :fqp => /[a-zA-Z0-9\/]*/ }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, however, there also is route globbing, I'll post an answer to detail that.

Comment: @Femaref Yes, there is, but IMO constraints are cleaner and more predictable, so I didn't include that.

Comment: I'll accept your answer as I agree with you on the general case.

Comment: @Femaref The funny part is that I used to think otherwise, [not too long ago](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8650366/438992). Ultimately it just depends--for filenames, constraints are a better option, IMO.

Comment: In the end it will be past through [grit](https://github.com/mojombo/grit) and a hash will be generated, based on that the actual file will be accessed. So it doesn't really matter in this case.

Comment: @Femaref Oh; the question is a bit misleading then, since there's not really a security risk if you're accessing stuff that your user would normally have access to, no?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7124/discussion-between-femaref-and-dave-newton)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Deve Newton's answer, there also is route globbing, of the form

```
get "/page/*path", => "page#show"
```

It matches the `page` part and puts any additional content in the path as `params[:path]` in the detailed controller action.