# Routing a parameter that includes multiple consecutive slashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes, escaping, glob

NOTE: the advice from [Rails routing with a parameter that includes slash(/)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273205/rails-routing-with-a-parameter-that-includes-slash)

does not seem to work for me...

my route looks like:

```
get '/r/*code_or_url' => 'pixels#visit', :as => :visit, :format => false, :constraints => {:url => /.*/}, :escape => false
```

but if I go to

```
http://localhost:3000/r/http://www.google.com
```

I see:

No route matches [GET] "/www.google.com"

and my url bar is at

```
http://localhost:3000/www.google.com
```

my pixels_controller.rb looks like

```
def visit
  @code_or_url = params[:code_or_url]
  redirect_to @code_or_url
end
```

and the parameters in the logs are

```
Parameters: {"escape"=>false, "code_or_url"=>"http:/www.google.com"}
```

---

as of now, the only way i've found to do what I like is the following:

```
request.original_fullpath[3..-1]
```

everything else butchers the original request