# Ignore variable number of routing parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been struggling to find a way to ignore a variable number of route parameters that come after some specific point.

I'd like to route any type of these:

```
'/item/param1/:filename'
'/item/param1/param2/:filename'
'/item/param1/..../paramn/:filename'
```

to plain

```
'/item/:filename'
```

`:filename` **can contain any character**, including spaces and dots, except '/'.
All parameters should be ignored except the first and the last.

Basically, I'm trying to implement a catch-all route.

I've tried different approaches, around

`match '/item/*filename'`

to no avail and I've ended "bruteforcing it" with a limited number of optional parameters, to something like this:

```
match '/item(/:a(/:b(/:c(/:d(/:e)))))/*filename', :constraints => { :filename => /[^\/]*/ }, to: "controller#action", via: :get, format: false
```

It works, but I know there must be a more elegant way of doing it.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails routing with a parameter that includes slash(/)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273205/rails-routing-with-a-parameter-that-includes-slash)

Comment: I just tried it. It passes the slashes also to filename. I don't want that. It's a catch-all I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: How about `match '/item(/:a)/*filename, :constraints => { :a => /.*/, :filename => /[^\/]*/ }, to: "controller#action", via: :get, format: false`?

Comment: Make it an answer and you are +25 !!

Comment: In other words, Uri's solution works perfect