# How to put a member of a routing resource outside of it's parent namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I want to get:

```
helper              | path             | action
--------------------|------------------|---------
file_path           | GET /file        | file#index
file_path(id)       | GET /file/:id    | file#show
show2_file_path(id) | GET /show2/:id   | file#show2  <-- This is hard.
```

where `:id` has the same `constraint: {id: /.+/}` on all routes.

Interpretation: I want a second way to show a file or directory called `show2`.

Root of the problem: I cannot use `/file/:id/show2` because `:id` is a file path and may contain slashes. So it would be ambiguous if a file was named `show2`.

The best I could find up to now was the very explicit:

```
resources :file, only: [:index, :show], constraints: { id: /./ }
get 'show2/:id' => 'file#show2', constraints: { id: /./ }, as: :show2_file
```

but I am not satisfied because I am repeating:

- the constraint and the controller name `file` between line 1 and 2
- the action name `show2` is repeated 3 times on line 2

I wish I could write it as something like a "shallow member":

```
resources :file, only: [:index, :show], constraints: { id: /./ } do
  member do
    get :show2, shallow: true
  end
end
```

which would combine:

- member characteristics: reuse the parent controller
- shallow characteristics: don't use the parent namespace in the path

Related questions:

- [Rails routing with a parameter that includes slash(/)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273205/rails-routing-with-a-parameter-that-includes-slash): no mention about resources

Comment: first of all `resource` != `resources` and in your case should be `resources`

Comment: you want define route as `member` but you don't want behaviour as for member(why?), so I'm not sure that `member` can help you. If you want independent path so you should define it as separate route.

Comment: I want the same controller and constraints as the resource, like in member. I can't help feeling that the line `get 'show2/:id' => 'file#show2', constraints: { id: /./ }, as: :show2_file` could be DRYed out.

Comment: `show2/:id` is incorrect just because `show2` is not resources, but you want use it like `resources`, correct should be `files/:id/show2`